# How to transfer data from Genymotion to host machine?

Tags: virtualbox, android-sdk, genymotion

I am using Genymotion version 2.3.1 in my Ubuntu machine. I am able to copy files from the host machine to Genymotion by a simple drag and drop method. But I am unable to copy Genymotion data to the host machine. I want to move data from Genymotion to the host machine. How I can transfer data?

Comment: As a workaround, you can use any file uploading service.

Comment: @Smile4ever But it is costly and time consuming also...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

- Go to your VirtualBox VM settings Shared folder tab (open **VirtualBox** > select the Android/Genymotion virtual machine > **Settings > Shared folders**)
- Add a shared folder with the folder you want to share, and check the *auto mount* and *permanent* options
- Start your VM as usual from the Genymotion software
- Your shared folder is available in the `/mnt/shared` directory (multiple shared folders are supported)

Source: [Accessing files from Genymotion SD card | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported with Android 10 (API 29) virtual devices.
But You can connect your Android phone to Genymotion and copy your data.

Comment: I think this answer is less relevant to OP's Genymotion version or overall problem, as it was asked almost 6 years ago, way before Android 10 was introduced..