# How to directly save files into host machine from genymotion?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, genymotion, whatsapp

When I use whatsapp, Telegram etc on Genymotion. Files from that app can be download in Genymotion Virtual Device, but saving that files [video photo etc]
in Genymotion virtual Device is contain to much memory and after deleting that files machine can not make free space, so is it any option to save automatically whatsapp/genymotion data into host directly.

In short Save Whatsapp files directly into host machine from Genymotion.

I read below link:-
[How to transfer data from Genymotion to Host machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627238/how-to-transfer-data-from-genymotion-to-host-machine)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530114/accessing-files-from-genymotion-sd-card